# Converting strings to number inside python dictionary parsed from Grass

Tags: python, grass

After parsing a Grass GIS modules inside Python, I am trying to use this dictionary on my next step of raster calculation. But everything from the parsed dictionary is passed as strings.

```
# original grass command used:
# r.stat= gscript.parse_command('r.info', flags = 'r', map='HC1015.5')

# here is dict output to reuse
r.stat={u'max': u'95.7933959960938', u'min': u'1.41131834257793'}
```

To be able to use the dictionary, I like to use the dictionary keys directly but their respective values need to be converted into floats.

I have hacked it in this following way:

```
stat=r.stat.values()
r_max=float(stat[0]); r_min=float(stat[1])
```

Any Python tips for doing it easily while I am saving the parsed dectionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change dictionary you use `Dict Comprehensions`

```
stat={u'max': u'95.7933959960938', u'min': u'1.41131834257793'}

stat = {k: float(v) for k,v in stat.items()}  

print(stat)
```

**Output**

```
{'max': 95.7933959960938, 'min': 1.41131834257793}
```